# Css slide up and down div's over image on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently trying to create using css3; an image that when you hover over it a box slides down and another up. They will slide over the image and contain content about the image and other stuff.

I've found some good tutorials but none with what I'm looking for, well not exactly anyway. I've been googling for a while now so I'm just wondering if anyone can point me to a good tutorial or can help me with it?

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var thumbs = $("ul li img");
for (var i = 0, ii = thumbs.length; i < ii; i++) {
    if (thumbs[i].title && thumbs[i].title.length > 0) {
        var imgtitle = thumbs[i].title;
        $(thumbs[i]).wrap('<div class="wrapper" />').after('<div class=\'caption\'>' + imgtitle + '</div>').removeAttr('title');
    }
}

$('.wrapper').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('img').animate({
        opacity: ".6"
    }, 300);
    $(this).find('.caption').animate({
        top: "-85px"
    }, 300);
}, function () {
    $(this).find('img').animate({
        opacity: "1.0"
    }, 300);
    $(this).find('.caption').animate({
        top: "85px"
    }, 100);
});
});
```

CSS:

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#main {
    width:790px;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 auto;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding:30px;
    margin-top:30px;
}
#main h3 {
    font-family:'Droid Sans', arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:50px;
    letter-spacing:-2px;
    text-shadow:1px 2px 2px #999;
    padding:0 8px;
}
#main p {
    font-family:Georgia, arial;
    font-size:16px;
    background:#ececec;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid #d2d2d2;
    clear:both;
    margin:25px 8px;
    text-shadow:0 1px 1px #fff;
}
#main a {
    float:right;
    font-family:Georgia;
    font-size:16px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#990000;
    position:relative;
    left:-20px;
    padding:25px 0 0 0;
}
ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
ul li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    line-height:10px;
    width:218px;
    height:218px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #d2d2d2;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    background:#ececec;
}
/*dynamically added*/
 div.wrapper {
    width:218px;
    height:218px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

div.caption {
    font-family:'Reenie Beanie', arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:34px;
    letter-spacing:-2px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    padding:55px 15px 15px 15px;
    background:url(images/caption-bg.png) repeat-x;
    min-height:125px;
    color:#d20000;
    text-shadow:0 1px 1px #999;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    line-height:16px;
}
ul li:nth-child(1) div.caption {
    font-family:'Reenie Beanie', arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:34px;
    letter-spacing:-2px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    padding:55px 15px 15px 15px;
    background:url(images/caption-bg.png) repeat-x;
    min-height:125px;
    color:#d20000;
    text-shadow:0 1px 1px #999;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    line-height:16px;
}
ul li:nth-child(2) div.caption {
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:26px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    padding:45px 15px 15px 15px;
    background:url(images/city.png);
    min-height:125px;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:1px 2px 1px #999;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    line-height:16px;
}

ul li:nth-child(3) div.caption {
    font-family: Georgia, arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:24px;
    font-style:italic;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    padding:35px 15px 15px 15px;
    background:url(images/wood.png);
    min-height:125px;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:1px 2px 1px #000;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    line-height:16px;
}
ul li:nth-child(4) div.caption {
    font-family:'Droid Sans', arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:30px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    padding:15px;
    background:url(images/grass.png) repeat-x;
    min-height:125px;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:1px 2px 1px #000;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    line-height:30px;
}
ul li:nth-child(5) div.caption {
    font-family:'Lobster', arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:30px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    padding:38px 15px 15px 15px;
    background:url(images/green.png) repeat-x;
    min-height:125px;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:1px 2px 1px #ff4e00;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    line-height:16px;
}
ul li:nth-child(6) div.caption {
    font-family:'IM Fell English SC', arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:30px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    padding:35px 0 0 0px;
    background:url(images/grunge.png);
    min-height:125px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:30px;
    letter-spacing:-2px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, requests for tutorials are off-topic here. This site is for *specific* programming problems. If you have an implementation of what you are trying to do that isn't *quite* there, feel free to share that code in your question and we can respond with answers to solve the remaining (specific, code-related) problems.

Comment: Very sorry about that, I didn't know. I should have read the forum rules which I will do now :)   I'm trying to create two divs with content(image description and share the image link to facebook etc and info about the uploader)  The piece I'm stuck with however is not calling the content or sharing the image link via social media but rather the simple css that animates the divs, up and down over the image that contains this information. I know very silly however I haven't programmed in a few years and I just can't get my head around it for some reason.

Comment: No harm; no foul. *Do* note that this is **not** a forum, however :-) It would be dangerous to treat it as such. What I mean by that is, discussion that would be at home in a forum is discouraged here. Stack Overflow is a down-to-business, no-nonsense (usually) repository for every programming question ever.

Comment: In the future, add that to your question by editing it, not by posting comments :-)

Comment: @TylerH Sorry, I will in the future. I'm just zombified and a fool right now.

Comment: to be able to respond more quickly you can use these website: [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/) and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `hover` event is not working as the `wrapper` elements are added dynamically. Events, like `click()` or `hover()`, can only be attached to elements that are already in the DOM when the page is loaded.
To attach events to dynamically added elements, you can delgate the event from a parent element that is already in the DOM to the added element using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - e.g. for attaching a  `click()` event to an added `div` with the class `wrapper` `$(".wrapper").click(function(){...});` wouldn't work, instead you can delegate the event using `on()` like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".wrapper", function(){...});
```

Instead of `$(document)` every parent element of the added `.wrapper` can be used to delegate the event - in case `#main` is a parent element in your example you can attach for `hover()` the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events with `on()` like this:

```
$("#main").on(
 {
    mouseenter: function() { /* your animations */ },
    mouseleave: function() { /* your animations */ }
 },
  ".wrapper");
```

I've just added your CSS and the adjusted script together with some example HTML in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8u05w4j9/)

As you mentioned in your question that you tried to animate the `div` with the caption using CSS3, I've adjusted this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xea9h6n4/) to display the same animations using CSS transitions instead of jQuery. E.g. for animating the caption it's just

```
.caption {
   top:0;
   transition: 1s;
}
.wrapper:hover .caption {
  transition: 1s;
  top: -85px;
}
```

**Update:** For the aditional question in the comment how to adjust the `wrapper` to the actual image size - 2 solutions. For both, remove the values for `width` and `height` that you've set for `ul li` and `div.wrapper`.

**1:** You can set the image size and width to each image:

```
<img title="cat" width="300" height="200" src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" />
```

and just get the values in the part of your function where you already retrieve the title and set the values to the image wrapper:

```
if (thumbs[i].title && thumbs[i].title.length > 0) {
      var imgtitle = thumbs[i].title;
      var imgwidth = thumbs[i].width;
      var imgheight = thumbs[i].height;
      $(thumbs[i]).wrap('<div class="wrapper" style="height:' 
      + imgheight + 'px; width:' + imgwidth + 'px;" />')
      .after('<div class=\'caption\'>' + imgtitle + '</div>').removeAttr('title');
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2zd0Le6/) for this version.

**2:** You can retrieve the actual image width and height

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var thumbs = $("ul li img");
  for (var i = 0, ii = thumbs.length; i < ii; i++) {
    if (thumbs[i].title && thumbs[i].title.length > 0) {
        var imgtitle = thumbs[i].title;
        var imgsrc = thumbs[i].src;
        var image = $("<img />");
        image.attr("src", imgsrc + "?" + new Date().getTime());
        image.on("load", {
            current: thumbs[i]
        }, function (event) {
            var imgwidth = this.width;
            var imgheight = this.height;
            $(event.data.current).wrap('<div class="wrapper" style="height:' 
            + imgheight + 'px; width:' + imgwidth + 'px" />')
            .after('<div class=\'caption\'>' + imgtitle + '</div>').removeAttr('title');
        });
    }
  }
});
```

Because the images are not already in the DOM when the function is executed, it's not possible to just get the image width and size using the jQuery functions `width()` and `height()`. But it's possible to create an jQuery image object

```
var image = $("<img />");
```

and set the source of the current image in the `for` loop to this image:

```
var imgsrc = thumbs[i].src;
image.attr("src", imgsrc + "?" + new Date().getTime());
```

Adding `"?" + new Date().getTime());` to the image prevents that the image is retrieved from the browser cache and actually loaded (e.g. in case you would use the same image name for a new image with a different size).

The `load` event is attached to this image using the already known `on()`:

```
image.on("load", {current: thumbs[i]}, function (event) {
    ....
});
```

with the current image as additional parameter: `{ current: thumbs[i] }`

This parameter is accessible inside the `function(event){..}` as `event.data`, and the current image - `thumbs[i]` is retrieved as `event.data.current`.
So `$(event.data.current).wrap(..);` inside the function of the `load` event means the same as `$(thumbs[i]).wrap(..)` for the current image.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gt41d6yj/) for this version.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense thank you  I'll give it a go tomorrow and see if I can get what I need done.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Dottsie Glad if I was able to help you. I've just added a CSS solution for the animations as I'm not sure if you would like to animate using CSS instead of jQuery only because the jQuery animations weren't working or if the main question is how to animate using CSS.

Comment: I should have made that more clear.yeah I was looking for a solution using css,  thanks. My brain is away today. I think I'm all coded out for the night haha.

Comment: That's brilliant! I have one more issue however and can't seem to figure it out. I'm trying to get the image wrapper to automatically adjust to the size of the image. Any idea on how to go about this?

Comment: @Dottsie I've just updated my answer for the question how to set the size of the wrapper to the size of the image.

Comment: That's brilliant, you've been a great help. Thanks very much.I'll give that a go and see how it turns out. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Dottsie Glad I was able to help you :). If this answered your question, you can accept this answer so your question will be marked as closed/solved. As I noticed you're new to Stackoverflow and maybe  don't know how this works and why, just check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks very much. Yup I am new and it's good to know these things so thanks for that too. Oh and I accepted the answer :)